# How can I empty the cart contents without closing the session?

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

I'm following the tutorial on the Lift website: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-6.3.html#prev but I'm unable to figure out by myself how can I empty the Cart Contents without closing the session.

Comment: I have next to zero experience with Lift but it seems just setting back the cart's content to empty (and re-rendering) would do the trick. Something like `cart.contents.set(Vector.empty)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following method to the `Cart` class which will clear the cart by replacing the contents of the `ValueCell` with an empty `Vector`.

```
def removeAllItems() = contents.atomicUpdate(v => Vector.empty)
```

The comment by Regis Jean-Gilles will also work, but using the `atomicUpdate` method will handle synchronization.